# What is most secure way to use `pip` to maintain Python packages?

Tags: python, security, virtualenv, pip

I'm perplexed about how best to use `pip` in the face of security concerns about malicious packages or install scripts. I'm not much of a security expert, so I may just be confused (*bear with me*), but it seems  that there are 4, possibly overlapping, approaches:

**(1) Use `sudo pip` for everything**

This is how I do things now. I generally do not need virtualenvs and like the convenience of having all my packages work for all my tools. I also don't install a lot of experimental packages, sticking pretty much to the well-known and widely used ones (`matplotlib`, `six`, etc).

I gather this can be a risky approach though because the installation process has `su` privileges, and [could potentially do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056000/656912); however it has the advantage of protecting the `site-packages` directory from subsequent mischief by anything (not just packages) running as non-`su` after an install.

This approach also can't be completely avoided, as some packages (`pip` itself) need it to bootstrap any Python installation.

**(2) Create a `pip` user and give it ownership of `site-packages`**

This would [seem to have the advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056100/656912) of restricting what `pip` can do: all it can do is install to `site-packages`. But I'm not sure about side effects, or if it would even work (when, for example `pip` needs to put things in other locations). A more realistic variant of this is to set things up this way, and use `pip` as "pip-user" when it works, and as `su` when it doesn't.

**(3) Give myself ownership of `site-packages`**

I gather [this is a very had idea](https://superuser.com/a/700093/114642), but I'm not sure quite why. It would mean that any code I run would be able to tamper with `site-packages`; but it would mean that malicious install scripts could only damage things I can damage myself anyway.

**(4) "Use a virtualenv"**

This suggestion comes up a lot, but I don't see how it helps. It seems no different from 3 to me since it creates a `site-packages` that I own.

Which, if any of these approaches, or combinations of approaches, is best for ensuring that `pip` does not result in exposing my system? My concern is mostly with my system as a whole, and only secondarily with my Python installation in `site-packages` (which I can always rebuild if need be).

---

Part of the problem I have, is that a don't know how to weigh the risks. An example approach, that seems to make sense to my limited understanding is simply to do (1) for the most part, and use a virtualenv (4) for any package that I worry might damage my `site-packages`. Anything I've installed will still be able to damage anything I have access to, but that seems unavoidable, and at least things I don't have access to will be safe (except during the installation process itself). But I have trouble evaluating whether the protection this affords is worth the risk it creates.

Comment: If you think 3 and 4 are quite the same, I suggest you to read more what a virtualenv is. From the doc (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/): A Virtual Environment, put simply, is an isolated working copy of Python which allows you to work on a specific project without worry of affecting other projects.

Comment: @AndreadeMarco: Yes, but if an install script is malicious, it will do damage wherever it wants, won' it? And if something malicious has been installed in `site-packages` it's no different from something malicious installed anywhere — it will run with as me and do whatever damage I could do.

Comment: The key difference being that a virtualenv is "an **isolated** working copy of python"

Comment: Probably i miss what means *malicious* for you.

Comment: @AndreadeMarco: Good question. Let's say specifically (a) delete files or (b) transmit the contents of files to a third party.

Comment: @yuvi: In what sense would a virtualenv be "isolated" from the kind of malicious behavior I describe on the previous comment (either during the installation process, or after)?

Comment: The link you gave explains it -  " If you give yourself write privilege to the system site-packages, you're risking that any program [...] can inject malicious code into the system site-packages and obtain root privilege". In other words - if your site-packages is isolated and you're *not* using the **system site-packages**, then there's no risk giving yourself permissions for it (which is exactly what the virtualenv does)

Comment: @yuvi: So, for example, when I'm running an install script in a virtualenv, it will be unable to read files elsewhere on my system (say, my home folder), or delete them? How does that work? Doesn't a virtualenv only protect the system `site-packages` (and then only if it is root-owned)?

Comment: I have to say, I'm definitly not an expert on security, and I'm not completely sure how virtualenv works, but this is how I understand it - Say you create your virtualenv on your desktop and give yourself permission to its folder - even if a malicious program got in, it still wouldn't have permissions to the system files, right? That's not the case with the system site-packages, where a malicious program can gain root privilages and do whatever it wants

Comment: @yuvi: So no different from (3), right?

Comment: It is different. The virtualenv you create has its own site-packages and its own pip, by installing inside it you're preventing from any malicious programs you accidentaly install from accessing your system site-packages, and thus it cannot gain root privilages and "only damage what you can damage"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at using a virtualenv. To quote [the docs](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html):

> Virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments. The basic problem
>   being addressed is one of dependencies and versions, and indirectly
>   permissions.

Virtualenv will create a folder with an isolated copy of python, an isolated pip and an isolated site-packages. You're thinking that this is the same as option 3 because you're taking that advice you linked at face value and not reading into it:

> If you give yourself write privilege to the system site-packages,
>   you're risking that any program that runs under you (not necessarily
>   python program) can inject malicious code into the system
>   site-packages and obtain root privilege.

The problem is not with having access to site-packages (you have to have privilages for site-packages to be able to do *anything*). The problem is with having access to the **system site-packages**. A virtual environment's site-packages does not expose root privilages to malicious code the same as the one that your entire system is using.

However, I see nothing wrong with using `sudo pip` for well known and familiar packages. At the end of the day, it's like installing any other program, even non-python. If you go to its website and it looks honest and you trust it, there's no reason not to sudo.

moreover, pip is pretty safe - it uses https for pypi and if you `--allow-external` it will download packages from third-party, but will [still keep checksums on pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021326/security-considerations-of-pip-allow-external/21069581#21069581) and compare them. For third-party with no checksum you need to explicitly call `--allow-unverified` which is the only option considered unsafe.

As a personal note, I can add that I use sudo pip most of the times, but as a WEB developer virtualenv is kind of a day-to-day thing, and I can recommend using it as well (especially if you see anything sketchy but you still want to try it out).

Comment: How, specifically, is that different from option (3)? That's what's not clear to me.

Comment: So when I `pip` in the system `site-packages` (e.g., on OSX `/Library/Python/X.X/site-packages/`, even if I own the directory, a malicious install script could acquire root privileges? And this is not the case when I `pip` in a virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why the system pip needs sudo privilages to work and the virtual one doesn't

Comment: It would still need `sudo` if I took ownership `site-packages`? That's now how I was interpreting [the suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056100/656912).

Comment: No no no. Open up the virtualenv somewhere you already have access to as a non-root user. On your desktop, in your documents directory, etc.

Comment: So it's no different from 3 then. If I take over ownership of the system `site-packages`, and `pip` as me, it's just like creating a new `site-packages` as me, which is what virtualenv does (unless it does more than you've said so far).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius There's nothing wrong with being the owner of site-packages unless it's the system site-packages

Comment: But how is it different? Other than the fact that I'm obviously installing over the system `site-packages` and could accidentally disrupt the system Python installation, how does it create a different *security* risk for my entire machine. What's different about malicious code running in the system's `site-packages` (that I own) or during installation there, vs. a `site-packages` in another location that I own?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45051/discussion-between-yuvi-and-raxacoricofallapatorius)

Comment: @connorbode that sentence is only dumb if you cut it out of context and completely ignore everything else I wrote. There's nothing constructive about your comment

Comment: @yuvi this is a question about security and you're saying there's nothing wrong with using sudo to install stuff. "it's the same as installing any other program, non-python" -- true, but you still NEVER give root access to some random program from the internet.  everything else about the answer was fine, but indeed, you've totally ruined it by suggesting `sudo pip install ANYTHING` is a good idea.

Comment: @connorbode I never said it was a good idea to install any random program from the internet with sudo. what I said, specifically, is that it was ok for *"well known and familiar packages"*. e.g., I don't see anything wrong with sudo installing packages like Numpy, Django, Requests, etc.

Comment: @yuvi they're public repos that anyone can contribute to.  it's quite possible that someone can sneak something nasty into them, hence if you have the option don't sudo.  well known != safe.  (for example, with another package manager, https://medium.com/@vesirin/how-i-gained-commit-access-to-homebrew-in-30-minutes-2ae314df03ab)

Comment: @connorbode It's possible, but if you're afraid of that, I explained how to avoid using sudo. That's really the users decision who to trust, and his responsibility when he uses sudo commands (again, not just for python)