# Automatic installation of dependencies when publishing Python 3 project on pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I want to publish a project using pypi. Ideally I would like the installation to be:

```
sudo pip3 install ProjectName
```

The problem is, I get:

> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the
>   requirement itsdangerous 
>   (from ProjectName)   Some insecure and unverifiable files were
>   ignored (use --allow-unverified itsdangerous to allow).

If I firstly install the external requirements (itsdangerous and wspy in this case), then the installation completes.

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
requests>=2.10.0
six>=1.10.0
itsdangerous==0.24
ws4py==0.3.4
```

And here is the install_requires from setup.py:

```
install_requires=[
    "requests",
    "six",
    "ws4py",
    "itsdangerous"
]
```

One thing I think may cause the issue is that the requirements.txt is not included in MANIFEST.in, but I am not sure how to include it.

I am using https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/.

Basically, I have the same issue as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014238/pip-any-workaround-to-avoid-allow-external/23072180). I do not really understand the accepted answer.

Comment: what is with the --allow-unverified in there?

Comment: It's the message I receive when I try to install my published package using: sudo pip3 install MyProjectName

Comment: Why are you installing (polluting) on your system Python? You can create a virtualenv. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE because the library will be used by other users and I thought it would be easier for installation this way.

Comment: Did you specify *where* to install those from? Pip requires a source for external packets.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, I haven't. I thought pip will figure it out. When I enter *pip install itsdangerous* it installs without problems. Doesn't pip know how to find the dependencies?

Comment: right- `pip install itsdangerous` works fine, so I was wondering why you had `--allow-external --allow-unverified` in there?

Comment: @PaulBecotte It works. But when I try `pip install MyProject` and itsdangerous is one of the dependencies for `MyProject` it doesn't work. It throws the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Could we try? What's your `ProjectName` real name? Is your project currently on pypi?

Comment: Do you succeed to install your `ProjectName` app in a fresh virtualenv? I'm suspecting clashes with your system Python.

Comment: Can you update your question with a copy of your `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` (without sensible info). Which version of `pip` do you use. What’s `pip3`, an alias?

Comment: Since pip v8.0.0, `--allow-unverified` is a no-op. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/?highlight=--allow-unverified%20#release-notes

Comment: I added full list of requirements. `requests` and `six` install successfully. `itsdangerous` and `ws4py` cannot install. Here is the error message:
`Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external ws4py to allow).`

Comment: Not sure if it's important, but I am using https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123987/discussion-between-giliev-and-laurent-laporte).

Comment: I added link to a similary question. That's exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To install

Update your `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` and/or `/etc/pip.conf`.

Append the test repository to the `--find-links` option:

```
[install]
find-links =
    https://pypi.python.org/pypi
    https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
```

The order is important…

See the [Cofiguration](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration) topic in the documentation.

### To register and upload

See the [TestPypi](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TestPyPI) wiki page.

Comment: The solution didn't work well for me (maybe I did something wrong), but I got the idea. Some of the packages weren't available in TestPypi. I tried on pip, and everything worked well there.